# rsyslog discard message

Tags: rsyslog

I'm trying to discard any "kernel: nfs: Deprecated parameter 'intr'" messages from /var/log/messages
Rsyslog version: 8.1911.0-6.el8

In my /etc/rsyslog.conf file I have the following:

```
module(load="imuxsock"    # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
       SysSock.Use="off") # Turn off message reception via local log socket;
                          # local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
module(load="imjournal"             # provides access to the systemd journal
       StateFile="imjournal.state") # File to store the position in the journal

global(workDirectory="/var/lib/rsyslog")

module(load="builtin:omfile" Template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")

include(file="/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf" mode="optional")

:msg, contains, "nfs: Deprecated parameter"  stop

*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog

cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

The line that should discard the messages is:

`:msg, contains, "nfs: Deprecated parameter"  stop`

I still see that the messages getting logged. Any ideas?
PS., I do have additional conf files in /etc/rsyslog.d/ if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Discarding **specific** messages with *[property-based filters](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html)*.

> Property-based filters are unique to rsyslod. They allow to filter on any property, like HOSTNAME, syslogtag and msg.

To discard messages use a tilde "~".

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                   /var/log/messages
:msg, contains, "nfs: Deprecated parameter" ~
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                   /var/log/kern.log
```

The specified messages are written to *messages*. Then, all logs containing the string “nfs: deprecated” are discarded. That means the config file lines below the “discard line” will not be applied to this message. Then, all remaining lines will also be written to the file *kern*.

---

In your case it's possible that the messages still get logged (due to the additional *.conf* files in */etc/rsyslog.d/*. So if you want to be 100% sure that messages containing "nfs: Deprecated parameter" do not get logged, you have to check and (maybe) edit them too.

**P.S.** you probably want to look for all *rules* containing ***.info**